# How to pick values from inside a span using ruby watir?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am new to ruby-watir test automation.

I intend to read the value '$9,118 per week'for verification

HTML

```js
<p class="inline-result">Your repayments will be: <span>$9,118 per week</span></p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to retrieve the text within the <span> tag?  This'll do it: `browser.span.text`.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work for you? What errors were you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution really depends on how you can uniquely find that span element.

If that is the only span element on the page then you can simply do:

```
browser.span.text
#=> "$9,118 per week"
```

However, it is unlikely that it is the only span. The only thing that might be unique to the span is that it has "per week" as part of the text, which would allow you to do:

```
browser.span(text: /per week$/).text
#=> "$9,118 per week"
```

If that is not unique enough, you might need to start looking for the parent `p` element first. For example, if the class attribute is unique:

```
browser.p(class: 'inline-result').span.text
#=> "$9,118 per week"
```

Or if the paragraph text is unique:

```
browser.p(text: /^Your repayments will be: /).span.text
#=> "$9,118 per week"
```